# random variable with binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I have a probability space
$\omega = 2^{\{1,\ldots,n\}}$
$\sigma$-algebra $2^\omega$
and $P(\{s\})=(p^{|s|})*(1-p)^{(n-|s|)}$

I assume that $n=2k$,$k$ natural number

I need to find a random variable that will distribute like $\mathrm{Bin}(k,p^2)$

Can you help me with this please?

Thanks.
benny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $2 = n/k$.

Another hint: $p^2$ has the same exponent $2$ as $n/k$.

Comment: can't figure out how that helps

Comment: added another hint. of course, you can't expect us to solve the exercise for you.